# react native multislider is not showing up due to default error that can not be resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native application. I am currently creating a filter screen that filets price. I am specifically creating a slider that will change the price based on the multi slider. I am currently setting up the multi-slider. I am getting an error that I think is coming from some type of default function in the package.

here is the error:

```
 ERROR  Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

[[94,94,94,94,94,94,112],[19,19,17,19,17,19,9],[[43673,"RCTView",551,{"shadowRadius":1,"shadowOffset":{"height":3,"width":0},"borderColor":4292730333,"shadowOpacity":0.2,"borderWidth":1,"borderRadius":30,"shadowColor":4278190080,"backgroundColor":4294967295,"height":30,"accessibilityValue":{},"width":30,"accessibilityState":{}}],[43675,"RCTView",551,{"accessibilityValue":{},"onResponderTerminate":true,"onResponderMove":true,"onResponderRelease":true,"onResponderTerminationRequest":true,"onResponderGrant":true,"onStartShouldSetResponder":true,"accessibilityState":{},"accessible":true}],[43675,[43673]],[43677,"RCTView",551,{"borderRadius":15,"alignSelf":"stretch","alignItems":"center","backgroundColor":0,"accessibilityValue":{},"accessibilityState":{},"onResponderTerminationRequest":true,"onResponderTerminate":true,"onResponderMove":true,"onResponderStart":true,"onStartShouldSetResponderCapture":true,"onResponderRelease":true,"onResponderEnd":true,"onResponderReject":true,"justifyContent":"center","onStartShouldSetResponder":true,"onResponderGrant":true,"onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture":true,"onMoveShouldSetResponder":true}],[43677,[43675]],[1449,40539]],35866]
```

this is the PriceOptions:

```
const PriceOptions = {
  0:'0',
  50000:'50K',
  100000:'100K',
  150000:'150K',
  200000:'200K',
  250000:'250K',
  300000:'300K',
  350000:'350K',
  400000:'400K',
  450000:'450K',
  500000:'500K',
  550000:'550K',
  600000:'600K',
  650000:'650K',
  700000:'700K',
  750000:'750K',
  800000:'800K',
  850000:'850K',
  900000:'900K',
  950000:'950K',
  1000000:'1M',
  1500000:'1.5M',
  2000000:'2M',
  2500000:'2.5M',
  3000000:'3M',
  3500000:'3.5M',
  4000000:'4M',
  4500000:'4.5M',
  5000000:'6M',
  6000000:'6.5M',
  7000000:'7M',
  8000000:'8M',
  9000000:'9M',
  10000000:'10M',
  11000000:'11M+',
}
```

Here are the parts of my code that use use the multislider:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Dimensions, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import MultiSlider from '@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider';

import { FilterSortContext } from '../../../../context/FilterSortContext'
import { PriceOptions, bedBathOptions } from '../../../../../utilities'

const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

const FilterComponent = () => {

  const {isSingleFamily, setIsSingleFamily,
    isMultiFamily, setIsMultiFamily,
    isCondo, setIsCondo,
    isTownhouse, setIsTownhouse,
    isApartment, setIsApartment} = useContext(FilterSortContext)

  const {
    beds, setBeds,
    baths, setBaths
  } = useContext(FilterSortContext)

  const {
    priceMin, setPriceMin,
    priceMax, setPriceMax,
    sqftMin, setSqftMin,
    sqftMax, setSqftMax,
    hoaMax, setHoaMax
  } = useContext(FilterSortContext)

  const updatePriceSliderValues = (value) => {
    setPriceMin(value[0])
    setPriceMax(value[1])
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.overlay}></View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
          ...
          <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
            ...
            <View style={styles.subHeadContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.subHeaderText}>Price:</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.multisliderContainer}>
              <MultiSlider
                optionsArray={PriceOptions}
                min={priceMin}
                max={priceMax}
                values={[priceMin, priceMax]}
                enabledTwo={true}
                enabledOne={true}
                onValuesChange={(value) => {updatePriceSliderValues(value)}}
                touchDimensions={{height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  borderRadius: 15,
                  slipDisplacement: 200}}
            />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: deviceHeight,
    width: deviceWidth,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    opacity: .5,
    zIndex: 2
  },
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: deviceHeight,
    width: deviceWidth,
    zIndex: 3
  },
  filterContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',
    width: deviceWidth - 20,
    height: deviceHeight - 200,
    zIndex: 2,
    borderRadius: 8, 
    padding: 8
  },
  headerContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 26,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingVertical: 16
  },
  subHeadContainer: {
    paddingBottom: 12
  },
  subHeaderText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '600'
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    paddingVertical: 12
  },

  homeTypeContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  row: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  homeTypeItem: {
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderRadius: 8
  },
  homeTypeItemSelected: {
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#0039a6'
  },
  homeTypeText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500'
  },
  homeTypeTextSelected: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: 'white'
  },
  bedBathContainerSelected: {
    paddingVertical: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 38,
    backgroundColor: '#0039a6',
    marginRight: 8,
    marginBottom: 12
  },
  bedBathTextSelected: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: '500'
  },
  bedBathContainer: {
    paddingVertical: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 38,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    marginRight: 8
  },
  bedBathText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight: '500'
  },
  multisliderContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
})

export default FilterComponent
```